# Can I use UML for modelling website navigation

Tags: uml

Can I use UML for modelling website navigation? If so someone give me some books/links for referrence (UML for websites kind of...!!!). If not so what are the tools for this?
  And basically I am a programmer and when I designed my previous website I just sketched down different page design ideas on paper and opted the one that I felt suitable. Then I did implement that design using html/css from scratch.

Is this the approach generally taken by all or have tools for drawing the to be implemented website designs (Wireframe kind of..)? Is the CMS meant for this? Please guide me on this.

Thanks

Comment: UML is the single most abused "programming" concept on earth...

Comment: @Stargazer712 How exactly is this an abuse of UML?  It is perfectly valid in most cases to conceptualise UI navigation as a state machine.

Comment: @CraftBeerHipsterDude, UML and bureaucracy are first cousins. Real world companies that get things done (emphasis on: **that get things done**), don't use UML. Rather, they use informal drawings that describe relationships between components in a way that is quick to draw but still communicates the information.

Comment: @riwalk Consider dialling down the rhetoric a notch-or-ten, your ignorance is showing.

Comment: @DaffyPunk I'm struggling to find a reason why your opinion should matter to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From time to time, I'll (ab)use a state diagram to lay out a site.  Each "state" represents a page (or group of pages), each "transition" a flow from one page (group) to another.

I don't try to capture all navigation: that becomes impractically noisy very quickly.  However it can be useful for capturing primary flows, e.g:

- Arrive at home page, select login, navigate to login page
- Enter credentials
- If credentials correct: navigate to post-login landing page
- otherwise: remain on login page

etc.

It's not a 'proper' state diagram but can be useful.  You might also want to look at [Garrett Information Architecture](http://www.jjg.net/ia/visvocab/).  It's a bespoke notation for the same problem but has a richer set of symbols.

hth.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe, you will find this article useful :
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4697.html

This article detailing user interface navigation via UML Activity Diagrams.

Comment: looks like link is not valid anymore

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at [UWE](http://uwe.pst.ifi.lmu.de/index.html), as it is as close as possible to UML and can do the job. The only problem is that there aren't many tutorials or documentation available.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using UML in other parts of the design process, it makes sense to ensure that the user interface you put together meets your use cases.  However, I've never used UML to actually design the layout or flow of a site.

We use [Axure](http://www.axure.com/) to mock up user interfaces, as this helps to let the customer/user have a play with the flow before spending time crafting the actual pages.

That said, I still do my website design using a pencil and paper.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.

UML State Diagrams works quite well for this purpose.  I have worked at large companies where this was standard practice, and with great success (even when keeping within strict UML rules and practices).

The key is to keep in mind what it is what you want to communicate with your diagram, and not try to model too many aspects within a single diagram.  And also, keep in mind your audience.  If you have to explain UML to them how UML works, then UML is not suitable for your situation.

I strongly disagree with those who think this is an "abuse" of UML.  Consider that state diagrams represents the different states of a system and the transitions between them as brought about by events.  When representing UI navigation, you are presenting UI forms as state and user actions and UI events as the events that brings about a change within the context of the UI instance of the system being presented to the user.

You are welcome to disagree with me, but please provide proof or support of your argument.