# Model JavaScript changes to HTML using UML?

Tags: javascript, ajax, uml

I'm working in a complicated PHP system that uses AJAX calls - made by the user selecting content from menus - to build up a SQL search string.  Each additional content added to the search criteria removes that content from the menu using AJAX.  For example adding criteria for `customer identification`removes the entry from the menu.  This makes sense as if the criteria is already added to the search terms, then it surely makes sense to prevent the user re-selecting the criteria again.

Keeping track to changes to the views, through removing the selected criteria from the menu, is becoming very complicated using JQuery.   To get to the point, is there a good way (perhaps using UML) to model how changes are being made to the HTML depending on the JavaScript.  I'm noticing quite a few bugs creeping in.

Comment: **(1)** similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227950/can-i-use-uml-for-modelling-website-navigation **(2)** related article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface_modeling **(3)** perhaps relevant example: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/examples/online-shopping-uml-communication-diagram-example.html?context=cmm-examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two UML diagrams come to mind that could be useful, and possibly three.  You can use a Class diagram to model out your menu structure.  A given menu item would be a class, have a boolean attribute Available, and would have a composition relationship with submenu items.  The submenu items have a constraint, such that they are not available if their parent menu item is not available.

You can use an Activity diagram to model out the behavior of a Use Case in detail.  You can use a Use Case diagram to model the system and how users ("Actors") interact with it.